# Oracle - MV on prebuilt table with MV log on same table

Tags: oracle, logging, view, materialized

We have an Oracle 11g OLTP database that has a fairly large table on it (60 million). I will call this table, table_a. Table_a has an MV log on it (log_a). The table is replicated to an ad hoc database that is read only, via an MV using fast refresh, on a prebuilt table, table_b. This works quite well.

However, we have a third party who has access to only our read-only ad hoc database. This third party needs to replicate table_b.

While I can create an MV log (log_b) on table_b, when I refresh table_b from table_a using log_a, log_b does not seem to get populated with the changes to table_b.

Has anyone ever tried this before and is there any way to get log_b to log the changes that occurred during the table_b refresh?